# Angular : get the data from selected index from ngFor loop

Tags: angular

So, in the parent component, I am running `*ngFor` loop.
and showing child component from `*ngFor` loop. But when I clicked on some value in child component I want to get the data related to the clicked element.

component:- **featureLayers.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let featureLayer of featureLayers">
   <feature-layer [featureLayer]="featureLayer"></feature-layer>
</div>
```

component:- **featureLayer.html**

```
<div class='feature-layer'>
  <p> {{featureLayer?.title}}</p>
  <img class="thumbnail-featurelayer-img" [src]="imageSrc" alt="featureLayer thumbnail" />
  <button class="btn-on-img" (click)="getFeatureData($event);">{{'common.choose'| translate}}</button>
</div>
```

`getFeatureData($event)` should return me data related to clicked image. I meant i should get title and image src

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean it should return you the data? `$event` doesn't have any value.

Answer (score 0):

just use `(click)="getFeatureData(featureLayer);"`. callback is called exactly with params you are passing in the template. In your case it is click event. with my code it will be featureLayer object